# how prevent pdf from downloading automatically?

Tags: html, pdf, download

i want to show a pdf file in my website.
it looks good when i use each of embed , object , iframe html tags and also librarys such as pdf.js
but the problem is when a user have windows and IDM (internet download manager) , IDM automatically capture the pdf and then in those tag elements nothing is visible except a black area!
how can i solve this foolish problem ?
thank.

Comment: Please show the code you have tried

Comment: yes show your code please

Comment: there is no code! i tested embed , object and iframe html tags. and also i used PDF.js library but no one works prefectly. those seem good but when i open browser to show pdf , my idm (internet download manager ) raise and automatically download the pdf and prevents browser from showing it.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out this website [ViewerJS](http://viewerjs.org/), which includes an opensource project.

Comment: soory but my porpuse was prevent idm (internet download manager) to automaticly download my pdf. even when i opened above link my idm automaticly raised and dowloaded the inner pdf.